# driver.manage(...).timeouts is not a function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, exception, nodejs, timeout

I'm using Node.js selenium-webdriver and I have this annoying issue. The issue is that the wait function throws an exception in console.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until=webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('https://****');

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='email-wrapper']/input")).sendKeys("user@mail.com").then(function(element){
    console.log("success "+ element);
});

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='password-wrapper']/input")).sendKeys("123456").then(function(element){
    console.log("success "+ element);
});

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='button']/button")).getText().then(function(text){
    console.log("Button text "+ text);
});

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='button']/button")).click().then(function(element){
    console.log("Button found "+ element);
});

driver.sleep(10000);
driver.quit();
```

Exception:

```
C:\\webdrivertut\library.js:13
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitWait(5000);
                        ^

TypeError: driver.manage(...).timeouts is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\webdrivertut\library.js:13:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Answer (score 4):

"chromedriver": "^2.36.0",
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",

here example of create driver function:

```
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver'
import chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome'
import chromedriver from 'chromedriver'
const TIMEOUT = 300000000

export default async () => {
 chrome.setDefaultService( new chrome.ServiceBuilder( 
chromedriver.path ).build() )

 const chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()

 const chromeOptions = { 'args': [ 'user-data-dir=/Users/user/selenium/bp/' ] }
chromeCapabilities.set( 'chromeOptions', chromeOptions )

 const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.withCapabilities( chromeCapabilities )
.build()

 await driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: TIMEOUT, pageLoad: 
TIMEOUT, script: TIMEOUT } )
console.info( await driver.manage().getTimeouts() )

 return driver
}
```

documentation: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Options.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue. It is due to a version issue. You can use:

`driver.manage().setTimeouts()` or `driver.sleep()`

please, check [the documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Options.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and this fixed it:

```
const capabilities = await driver.getCapabilities();
capabilities['map_'].set('timeouts', { implicit: TIMEOUT, pageLoad: TIMEOUT, script: TIMEOUT });
```

[getCapabilities()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_Builder.html#getCapabilities) retrieves the Map of the driver's capabilities which you can then interact with using the default methods outlined in the [MDN Javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

You can check that the capabilities are the ones you set by then logging them to the console

```
console.log(await driver.getCapabilities());
```

(edit: linked to the Selenium documentation)

Comment: +1 This probably works, but is a little bit more verbose than manage().setTimouts() :)

Comment: No error but don't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Since version v4.0.0-alpha.1 the `timeouts()` has been changed into **`setTimeouts()`**.

> API Changes: Changes to lib/webdriver.Options (driver.manage()):
>
> - Removed timeouts (use get/setTimeouts)
>
> Read more in the [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md)

Your code should look something like this:

```
driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: 5000 } )
```

See the [API documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Options.html) for others timeout parameters (e.g. pageLoad and script).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need more information into implicity

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);

like

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Downvoted, because timeouts() is replaced by setTimeouts() in the version the original poster is using.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitWait(5000);
```

should be

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
```

or

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The error shows you using `implicitWait` but the source code currently shows `implicitlyWait` (with"ly") so this is confusing unless it is being changed dynamically at runtime not by you.

Comment: Downvoted, because timeouts() is replaced by setTimeouts() in the version the original poster is using.

Answer (score 0):

It works and then stops the execution of subsequent code. So I tried using Promises:

```
this.driverWait = async function (explicitWaitMS) {
    // create a new promise inside of the async function
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(true), explicitWaitMS) // resolve
    });

    // wait for the promise to resolve
    await promise;
}
```